# Difference calculation within a numeric vector in R

Tags: r, subtraction

I have a vector

```
tyu <- c(11,8,5,4,2,1)
```

whose structure is

```
str(tyu)
num [1:6] 11 8 5 4 2 1
```

I would like to calculate the difference between the 1st value and the last value i.e the 6th value of the numeric vector using R programming

Answer would be = 11 - 1 = 10

Comment: `tyu[1] - tyu[length(tyu)]` or `head(tyu,1) - tail(tyu, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
tyu[1] - tyu[length(tyu)]
```

Or

```
head(tyu,1) - tail(tyu, 1)
```